# Search through the elements of an xml document in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an xml document i am trying to query and link the data to a listbox in windows phone 8 but i have so far failed. the examples online dont seem to bring what exactly i want.
Below is what i have at the moment. in xml.
This is my xml document(mydata.cml)

```
 <resources>
    <songCover>
        <item>Images/song1</item>
        <item>Images/song2</item>
         .....
    </songCover>
    <songName>
        <item>song1</item>
        <item>song2</item>
        .....
    </songName>
    <releaseYear>
        <item>2015</item>
        <item>2014</item>
         .....
    </releaseYear>
```

and the c#

```
     XDocument doc=XDocument.Load("mydata.xml");
     var data1=from Q in doc.Descedants("songCover") select new{Item=Q.Element("item").Value;
     var data2=from Q in doc.Descedants("songName") select new{Item=Q.Element("item").Value;
     var data3=from Q in doc.Descedants("releaseYear") select new{Item=Q.Element("item").Value;

foreach(var x in data1)
    foreach(var y in data2)
       foreach(var z in data3)
  //create a list of songs with there data eg [songCover1,song1,2015],[songCover2,song2,2014] etc
```

this is my xaml

```
<longlistselector>
......
<stackPanel>
    <image height=”100” width=”100” source={Binding data1} horizontal-alignment=left/>
    <textblock horizontal-alignment=right text={Binding data 2}/>
    <texblock horizontal-alignment=right text={Binding data 3}/>
</stackPanel>
......
</longlistselector>
```

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that number of items in each collection (songCovers, songNames, and releaseYears) are the same, and they corresponds by index, you can do this way :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("mydata.xml");
var data1 = doc.Descedants("songCover")
               .Elements("item")
               .Select(o => o.Value)
               .ToList();
var data2 = doc.Descedants("songName")
               .Elements("item")
               .Select(o => o.Value)
               .ToList();
var data3 = doc.Descedants("releaseYear")
               .Elements("item")
               .Select(o => o.Value)
               .ToList();

for(int i=0; i<data1.Count; i++)
{
    var songCover = data1[i];
    var songName = data2[i];
    var releaseYear = data3[i];
    //combine the 3 values above as needed
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.. This is exactly what I have  been looking for.. Now I can concentrate on figuring out how to bind it to a long list selector..... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?. I am assuming(base on what you wrote in your snippet as comment) covers, names and years are respectively at same position.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("path_here");
        XmlNodeList covers = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/songCover/item");
        XmlNodeList names = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/songName/item");
        XmlNodeList years = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/releaseYear/item");


        for(int i=0;i<covers.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[ "+ covers[i].Value +", " + names[i].Value + ", "+ years[i].Value  + " ]");
        }
```

Comment: XmlNodeList  and . SelectNode cannot be found in the name space, which reference do they use..

Comment: tried using XmlNode covers=xmlDoc.Nodes( "/songCover/item") 

Bt it also doesn't work

Comment: System.xml namespace

Comment: Doesn't exist.. Am using visual Studio 2013

Comment: try check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.xml(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: If you don't find this in your project try to add this dll fron references

Comment: Hey @null1941, I have failed to use XmlDocument so I made some research, and I found that XmlDocument has been replaced with XDocument in Windows phone 8.  How can I write your exact code using XDocument instead of XmlDocument? Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("file_path_here");
                List<xElement> covers = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/songCover/item").ToList();
                List<xElement> names = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/songName/item").ToList();
                List<xElement> years = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/releaseYear/item").ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < covers.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[ " + covers[i].Value + ", " + names[i].Value + ", " + years[i].Value + " ]");
                }
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for?